# I want to convert decimal digits to percentage in a column that has multiple data types

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to convert decimal digits to percentage in a column that has multiple data types in Power BI.
How do I achieve this using query/measure in Power BI?

Input data: Data type of the column: Any

[image: Input]

Expected output data

[image: Output]

I have already tried using manually, but I need to know how to get the output dynamically using query/measure in power BI

Comment: In Power Query, data types are defined at the field (column) level.  I suppose you could have your formula create a formatted text output.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Handle-formatting-with-multiple-data-type-in-same-column/m-p/823547) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a measure, column or calculated column? if measure or calculated column you can do this in the "format" section in "column tools" section.

If it is a measure you will see it in the "measure tools" in the format section as well.

In both cases there should be a drop down menu that allows you to format the output.

You can use this convention to make the measure:

```
MeasureName:=IFERROR(sum(TableName[ColumnName]),blank())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is actually a data column that is required to use in the reports. When I drag this field in the visualization the decimal numbers are not converting to percentage. I have already edited the column manually but I want to use a measure to this column to get automatically converted. Kindly assist me on this

Comment: when you click the column does the "measure tools" options become available?

Comment: No the measure tools are not available for this column. So I am trying to find a way to add a new measure to this column using query.

Comment: Then you first need to create a measure, so depending on the scalar value that you want, the formula may be `sum()`,  or others. Once you create the measure then you can format it to come up as percentage.

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to achieve but I am not able to write the query not sure what query should I write. Kindly let me know the formula that I can use in this measure.

Comment: I've updated the answer. However If you are unfamiliar how to create measures I would suggest taking a power bi course. Power BI can be powerful but it can quickly become confusing if you don't understand how to create measures, vs. calculated columns vs. regular columns.

Comment: if you the updated solution in the answer helps you please upvote it or accept it as answer